# SSO attempt within disparate Microsoft product set

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, crm, wif

I am looking at achieving a single sign-on user experience with a set of MS products (CRM, SharePoint, SSRS, ASP.NET), based on a token generated within an ASP.NET application driven by Windows Identity Foundation (WIF).

I wonder if there is a simple way to test / example out there whether a IP-STS token generated within an ASP.NET application will allow authentication with the other applciation types in the set? I do not have a SharePoint or CRM installation.

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prove and test?  Just that claims-based authentication will work in CRM and SharePoint?

Comment: @Garrett, that claims-based (i.e. using the IP-STS token) works with the set {CRM, SharePoint, ASP.NET, SSRS} without need for any further authentication. I am happy it works within ASP.NET but am looking to justify it will work with the larger set.

Answer (score 2):

One clarification: the token is **not generated within** the ASP.NET application. It is issued in an external entity which is called an IP-STS (or STS, or Identity Provider, or I-STS: all mean the same). Sometimes, the IP-STS is implemented with ASP.NET, but that's an implementation detail. The STS is ***not*** your app.

In general a token created for one app (the ASP.NET app, for example) cannot be reused in another one. But that is not a requirement for SSO with claims based identity.

With the details you provided, the simplest SSO experience with a 100% MSFT based portfolio of apps (custom or packaged) might be to just use Windows Authentication. Especially if you use AD for authentication. In this case, all just works.

A claims based approach makes sense when:

1. You have many identity providers (MSFT and non-MSFT, yours and
   your partners)
2. You want to enable federation scenarios (many
   companies interacting with each other)
3. You have a mix of
   technology stacks (both on the apps and the identity pieces)

If Windows Authentication is not feasible and you still want to use claims then you need to:

1. Identitfy which versions of the software you mention you eant to use (SharePoint 2010 and CRM 2011 are both claims enabled)
2. Provision an STS (e.g. ADFS or something else)

Comment: a token provider can be an ASP application (Passive-STS as far as I understand). But I understood a token to be issued by IP-STS to be usable by each application (CRM, SharePoint etc)?

Comment: Yes, and I-STS is a web site. Each application will get its own token. The SSO experience comes from the fact that the I-STS will authenticate the user only once (when the first token is requested). The subsequent tokens will be issued using the previous session the user has with it. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) and claims-based authentication are supported on the latest versions of SharePoint (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953202.aspx) and Dynamics CRM (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334502.aspx).

For SSRS, you'll need to create a custom security extension (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155029.aspx), or if it's in the context of SharePoint, you can configure it to use claims-based authentication: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487970.aspx.

If you are using these products, you should be able to achieve single sign-on with your other WIF-enabled ASP.NET applications.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention it also integrates with Office 365 and [Azure ACS](http://acs.codeplex.com/).

It also integrates with Java based products (OpenAM, Ping Identity ...) some of which are free but it's a ton of work to download, install and configure these.

I'm not aware of an "easy" way to prove this short of installing the product.

There's a ton of literature on the interoperability of WIF / ADFS / SSO. Is there a particular reason why you can't take this as read?

Comment: thanks. The demo a colleague is working with is having issues authenticating SSRS, ASP.NET ad CRM with a single token, so on paper works, not in practice.